# Trouble with type matching and IO in a recursive function

Tags: haskell, recursion, io, pattern-matching, type-mismatch

I'm experiencing some problems and can't find their reason. I am currently using the most recent version of GHCi portable - but to face the truth: It is my first time using Haskell, so as usual the problem is probably the user and not so much the system...

Problems that arise include:

- I am not completely sure I got the difference between `let x = 0` and `x <- 0` right. I understand that `let` is to be used with pure functions, `<-` with side effects (IO)? Someone please explain that to me once again.
- I have mismatchings between types, namely `String` and `(String,[Char])` (and sometimes others...). The compiler tells me that `String` was expected, although I clearly defined the function as `(String,String)`. What's going on? Did I somewhere make a mistake with the pattern matching?
- The recursion does not work as expected (i.e. doesn't work at all apparently). If someone could help me with that, I would be very grateful.

---

Here's what I want to do:
I am trying to write a little program that implements a finite state machine accepting a word. That means it takes a set of states, one of which is the start state, a list of accepting states, and a number of transition rules. (The alphabets which represent the possible input and states are somewhat implicit.) I don't want to go into too much detail about FSMs here.

However, this is how I figured a way to define such a FSM could look:

```
"a(b+|c+)"
"start"
["b","c"]
[
("start",   [('a',"a"),                         ('_',"reject")]),
("a",       [           ('b',"b"),  ('c',"c"),  ('_',"reject")]),
("b",       [           ('b',"b"),              ('_',"reject")]),
("c",       [                       ('c',"c"),  ('_',"reject")]),
("reject",  [                                   ('_',"reject")])
]
```

In the first line, we have short description of what the FSM is supposed to accept (in form of a regex in this case). It is only used to display it once.
The second line defines the start state, the third line a list of accepting states.
All following lines together are the transition rules. In this example, if we are in state "start" and read an input 'a', the next state is "a", if we read anything else, it is "reject". *(I am aware that I have not yet implemented the '_' meaning an else and the program will crash if an input is read for which no transition is defined.)*

So here comes the program:

```
module FSM where

import System.IO

main :: IO ()
main = do
    putStr "Enter file name: "
    fileName <- getLine
    (description, startState, acceptingStates, stateTransitions) <- (readDef fileName)
    putStrLn ("FSM description: " ++ description)
    putStr "Enter FSM input: "
    input <- getLine
    let input = reverse input
    putStrLn "----------------"
    let (finalState, oldStates) = changeState input startState stateTransitions
    putStrLn (oldStates ++ finalState)
    checkAcception finalState acceptingStates

--reads the specified .fsm file and returns
--  the description of the FSM (first line),
--  the start state (second line),
--  the list of accepting states (third line),
--  and the list of tuples containing all states and transitions (remaining lines)
readDef :: String -> IO (String, String, [String], [(String, [(Char,String)])])
readDef fileName = do
    contents <- readFile (fileName ++ ".fsm")
    let lineList = lines contents
    let description = read (head lineList)
    let startState = read (lineList !! 1)
    let acceptingStates = read (lineList !! 2)
    let stateTransitions = read (filter (/='\t') (concat (drop 3 lineList)))
    return (description, startState, acceptingStates, stateTransitions)

--recursive function that takes the input, start state, and state transitions
--and computes the new state by a call to itself with the old state and a part of the input
changeState :: String -> String -> [(String, [(Char,String)])] -> (String, String)

changeState startState [] _ = (startState, "")

changeState startState (x:xs) stateTransitions = do
    let (currentState, oldStates) = changeState xs startState stateTransitions
    let newState = findKey x (findKey currentState stateTransitions)
    let oldStates = (oldStates ++ currentState ++ " -(" ++ [x] ++ ")-> ")
    return (newState, oldStates)

--helper function to find a key in a list of tuples and return the corresponding value
--(because we are not using the map notation in the .fsm file)
findKey :: (Eq k) => k -> [(k,v)] -> v
findKey key xs = snd . head . filter (\(k,v) -> key == k) $ xs

--checks for a given state whether or not it is in the list of accepting states
checkAcception :: String -> [String] -> IO ()
checkAcception finalState acceptingStates = do
    let accept = any (==finalState) acceptingStates
    if accept
        then putStrLn "Input accepted!!"
        else putStrLn "Input rejected!!"
```

The idea is to have the user choose a file from which the definition is loaded (`readDef`, works like a charm). He is then prompted to enter some input the FSM works on.
The recursive `changeState` then does the actual work (doesn't work as well...).
Finally, the sequence of states and transitions is displayed and it is checked whether the final state is an accepting state (`checkAcceptance`).

---

Now, don't try to optimize what I have written. I know, the way the definition is modeled can be improved and many of the lines I wrote can be written far shorter using some high order Haskell foo. But please just help me with the issues listed above (and of course help me make it work).
Thanks a lot in advance.

One last thing: I'm trying some Haskell for a seminar at my university, so if someone from the Software Architecture Group googled my code and reads this: Hi :)

Comment: Please start at the beginning. Write *one* function. Make sure it compiles. Test it. If you're having trouble, ask a question here about the *one* function. Then move on to the next. Here you've dumped a whole messy slew of code and said "It doesn't work. Help me." Not too many will be interested in digging through all that.

Comment: Unrelatedly, it looks like you're using strings to represent what a LISP or Scheme programmer would use symbols for. In Haskell, we typically try, when we can, to use enumeration types for that. Write something like `data FSMState = Start | Stop | A | ...`. However, there are usually more natural representations of FSMs in Haskell.

Comment: @dfeuer Like I didn't think of that...
I am well aware that what I posted is not a concise question. But I think I indicated that I am not sure _which_ part of the code the problem arises from, so I better posted _all_ of it. On top of that, I have ofted read posts where an overly short question lead to even more questions, because the context or even the meaning was left unclear.
So to refine my request: I am especially unsure about the `changeState` part. The questions remain: Is my understanding of `let` correct? Is there an obvious type mismatch I caused? Is the idea of recursion correct?

Comment: No, `changeState` makes no sense that I can see. You don't need/want a `do` block there at all, as far as I can tell, and I have no idea what you mean about "old states". Isn't there just one current state and one next state?

Comment: Yes, there is of course always only one current state and one next state. However, if I want to print to the command line which states are being used, i.e. the transitions from start state to next to next ... to final state, I see two ways: 1. Do that in the recursive function. I would then need to define it as IO, but would actually like to keep it pure. 2. Build up a String oldStates recursively, that I return with the function and can print out later on.

Comment: The canonical way to record things as you go is using a writer monad. You likely want to use a big old combo platter called `RWST`, which can be found in the `mtl` package that comes with GHC. But I reiterate: you're trying to do too much at once. Smaller pieces, please! It's not just about asking the question, but about building up your own understanding of how things are done in Haskell before you try to go for big complicated things. I'm a (relative) beginner myself, and it's frustrating, yes, but that's how it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get things to compile by just changing the second clause of the `changeState` function to:

```
changeState startState (x:xs) stateTransitions =
    let (currentState, oldStates) = changeState xs startState stateTransitions
        newState = findKey x (findKey currentState stateTransitions)
        oldStates2 = (oldStates ++ currentState ++ " -(" ++ [x] ++ ")-> ")
    in (newState, oldStates2)
```

We've 1) removed the *do*, 2) combined the *let* clauses and 3) renamed the second occurrence of the *oldState* variable to *oldState2*. In Haskell we don't redefine variables - we just create a variable with a new name. Complete code is available here: http://lpaste.net/118404

When you write:

```
(new, old) = changeState ...
```

you are saying that changeState is a pure function. If you define `changeState` with `do ... return (...)` you are saying it is a monadic computation and when you call it you need to use the arrow `<-` in a `do` block:

```
(new, old) <- changeState ...
```

Since `changeState` is a pure function (doesn't need to do IO) you might as well keep it as a pure function, so there is no reason to use `do` and `return`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `do` notation and the `return` function don't do what you think they do. In Haskell: `return` doesn't signify that a function should end (even though it's most commonly seen at the end of functions); it just means that the argument should be wrapped in a `Monad`. Because the type of your function with all arguments applied is (String,String) the compiler thought you were trying to use something like this: (won't actually compile without GHC extensions, and will throw exceptions if used because I used `undefined`)

```
instance Monad ((,) String) where
  (>>=) = undefined :: (String,a) -> (a -> (String,b)) -> (String,b)
  return = undefined :: a -> (String,a)
```

But the compiler already knew that `(String,String) -> (String,String)` doesn't match `a -> (String,a)` so it didn't get as far as checking whether or not the instance exists.
Fixing this problem revealed another one: you define `oldStates` twice in the same function, which doesn't work in Haskell unless the two definitions are in different scopes.

This is your function modified to compile properly, but I haven't tested it.

```
changeState :: String -> String -> [(String, [(Char,String)])] -> (String, String)

changeState startState [] _ = (startState, "")

changeState startState (x:xs) stateTransitions = let
    (currentState, oldStates) = changeState xs startState stateTransitions
    newState = findKey x (findKey currentState stateTransitions)
    oldStates' = (oldStates ++ currentState ++ " -(" ++ [x] ++ ")-> ")
    in (newState, oldStates')
```